# Weird black line appears in vector density plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, color, vector

**Bug introduced in 13.0, persisting through 13.1.**

---

I am plotting a vector field `data` where the background color indicates the vector orientation. I use `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π), 0.8]]` to get the rainbow-like color. Working with MMA Version 13.0.1 on a mac in case it matters.

However, a black vertical line in the middle appears out of thin air. How to get rid of it?

If we commented out `MaxRecursion`, it could disappear. But I do need high enough `MaxRecursion` in order to get accurate plots in most cases.

[image]

```
data = {{{{-0.26`, -0.04`}, {0.7251542862020461`, 
      0.6885864224647483`}}, {{-0.26`, 
      0.004444444444444438`}, {0.8121180248865612`, 
      0.5834931993214237`}}, {{-0.26`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.8811364875617238`, 
      0.4728620203477842`}}, {{-0.26`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {0.9227870341189213`, 
      0.3853103809424353`}}, {{-0.26`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {0.9387404583547154`, 
      0.3446249437402623`}}, {{-0.26`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {0.9399044920889795`, 
      0.3414374697524531`}}, {{-0.26`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {0.9359387379799902`, 
      0.3521628582750081`}}, {{-0.26`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.9320161622080637`, 
      0.36241671233947315`}}, {{-0.26`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.9298547993488173`, 
      0.367926693959504`}}, {{-0.26`, 0.36`}, {0.9295066796287508`, 
      0.3688052772474045`}}}, {{{-0.20222222222222225`, -0.04`}, \
{0.8556862281880812`, 0.5174950037336158`}}, {{-0.20222222222222225`, 
      0.004444444444444438`}, {0.9366382828719669`, 
      0.3502980546030101`}}, {{-0.20222222222222225`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.9978730037786964`, 
      0.06518794619929208`}}, {{-0.20222222222222225`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {0.9737646644203485`, \
-0.2275574176473401`}}, {{-0.20222222222222225`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {0.9736609224239935`, \
-0.22800089505187915`}}, {{-0.20222222222222225`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {0.9994612127543253`, \
-0.03282200785529828`}}, {{-0.20222222222222225`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {0.9921701970481471`, 
      0.1248931546940847`}}, {{-0.20222222222222225`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.9780096688347512`, 
      0.20855955424228417`}}, {{-0.20222222222222225`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.9684918800506811`, 
      0.249045133009857`}}, {{-0.20222222222222225`, 
      0.36`}, {0.9635117236666386`, 
      0.26766613225610514`}}}, {{{-0.14444444444444446`, -0.04`}, \
{0.9285595029972205`, 0.3711835791000931`}}, {{-0.14444444444444446`, 
      0.004444444444444438`}, {0.9745915358918044`, 
      0.22398959388340717`}}, {{-0.14444444444444446`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.9466968491577266`, \
-0.3221258694902238`}}, {{-0.14444444444444446`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {-0.14406357977553372`, \
-0.9895684337034293`}}, {{-0.14444444444444446`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {-0.38683304517344397`, \
-0.9221497682924613`}}, {{-0.14444444444444446`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {0.06675217080553657`, \
-0.9977695864741262`}}, {{-0.14444444444444446`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {0.9356622664583724`, \
-0.3528967598689195`}}, {{-0.14444444444444446`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.9997553207759659`, 
      0.022120094487719903`}}, {{-0.14444444444444446`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.9914970015769683`, 
      0.1301295349406951`}}, {{-0.14444444444444446`, 
      0.36`}, {0.9854302489652773`, 
      0.17008005298750184`}}}, {{{-0.08666666666666667`, -0.04`}, \
{0.9686134796871743`, 0.24857177427918867`}}, {{-0.08666666666666667`,
       0.004444444444444438`}, {0.9821468295473782`, 
      0.18811593555579756`}}, {{-0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.999564444643616`, \
-0.029511370762798382`}}, {{-0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {-0.6306572010306724`, \
-0.7760615277077959`}}, {{-0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {-0.8639920532258941`, \
-0.503505443826086`}}, {{-0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {-0.854387321708981`, \
-0.5196367043454054`}}, {{-0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {-0.4647503397636045`, \
-0.8854417664022938`}}, {{-0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.9834815922465346`, \
-0.18100817029134625`}}, {{-0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.9993561016559114`, 
      0.03588010706644777`}}, {{-0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.36`}, {0.996200250424407`, 
      0.08709225599528819`}}}, {{{-0.02888888888888891`, -0.04`}, \
{0.9960399744529618`, 0.08890651996194232`}}, {{-0.02888888888888891`,
       0.004444444444444438`}, {0.9973486974476692`, 
      0.07277070632773598`}}, {{-0.02888888888888891`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.9996134862888723`, 
      0.027800683973717478`}}, {{-0.02888888888888891`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {-0.8541802659537857`, \
-0.5199769930055754`}}, {{-0.02888888888888891`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {-0.9855679393258248`, \
-0.16928035022721158`}}, {{-0.02888888888888891`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {-0.9874106472894941`, \
-0.15817779116975342`}}, {{-0.02888888888888891`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {-0.9744549840336947`, \
-0.22458291139775438`}}, {{-0.02888888888888891`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.9758236585083735`, \
-0.21855934547699685`}}, {{-0.02888888888888891`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.9999993818193678`, \
-0.0011119176597457494`}}, {{-0.02888888888888891`, 
      0.36`}, {0.9996786054596054`, 
      0.025351248220522333`}}}, {{{0.028888888888888853`, -0.04`}, \
{0.9960399744529619`, -0.08890651996194215`}}, \
{{0.028888888888888853`, 
      0.004444444444444438`}, {0.9973486974476691`, \
-0.07277070632773605`}}, {{0.028888888888888853`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.9996134862888723`, \
-0.027800683973717474`}}, {{0.028888888888888853`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {-0.854180265953787`, 
      0.519976993005573`}}, {{0.028888888888888853`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {-0.9855679393258248`, 
      0.16928035022721144`}}, {{0.028888888888888853`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {-0.9874106472894941`, 
      0.15817779116975347`}}, {{0.028888888888888853`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {-0.974454984033695`, 
      0.22458291139775366`}}, {{0.028888888888888853`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.9758236585083737`, 
      0.2185593454769964`}}, {{0.028888888888888853`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.999999381819368`, 
      0.0011119176597455553`}}, {{0.028888888888888853`, 
      0.36`}, {0.9996786054596054`, -0.02535124822052211`}}}, \
{{{0.08666666666666667`, -0.04`}, {0.9686134796871744`, \
-0.24857177427918864`}}, {{0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.004444444444444438`}, {0.9821468295473783`, \
-0.18811593555579761`}}, {{0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.9995644446436162`, 
      0.029511370762798177`}}, {{0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {-0.6306572010306719`, 
      0.7760615277077964`}}, {{0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {-0.8639920532258941`, 
      0.5035054438260858`}}, {{0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {-0.854387321708981`, 
      0.5196367043454054`}}, {{0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {-0.4647503397636051`, 
      0.8854417664022933`}}, {{0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.9834815922465344`, 
      0.18100817029134664`}}, {{0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.9993561016559114`, \
-0.0358801070664478`}}, {{0.08666666666666667`, 
      0.36`}, {0.996200250424407`, -0.0870922559952882`}}}, \
{{{0.14444444444444443`, -0.04`}, {0.9285595029972206`, \
-0.3711835791000928`}}, {{0.14444444444444443`, 
      0.004444444444444438`}, {0.9745915358918045`, \
-0.22398959388340747`}}, {{0.14444444444444443`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.9466968491577264`, 
      0.3221258694902242`}}, {{0.14444444444444443`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {-0.14406357977553294`, 
      0.9895684337034295`}}, {{0.14444444444444443`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {-0.38683304517344347`, 
      0.9221497682924616`}}, {{0.14444444444444443`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {0.0667521708055345`, 
      0.9977695864741261`}}, {{0.14444444444444443`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {0.9356622664583722`, 
      0.3528967598689197`}}, {{0.14444444444444443`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.999755320775966`, \
-0.022120094487719722`}}, {{0.14444444444444443`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.9914970015769683`, \
-0.13012953494069493`}}, {{0.14444444444444443`, 
      0.36`}, {0.9854302489652774`, -0.17008005298750178`}}}, \
{{{0.2022222222222222`, -0.04`}, {0.8556862281880813`, \
-0.5174950037336157`}}, {{0.2022222222222222`, 
      0.004444444444444438`}, {0.936638282871967`, \
-0.3502980546030096`}}, {{0.2022222222222222`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.9978730037786964`, \
-0.06518794619929158`}}, {{0.2022222222222222`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {0.9737646644203483`, 
      0.22755741764734116`}}, {{0.2022222222222222`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {0.9736609224239934`, 
      0.22800089505188031`}}, {{0.2022222222222222`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {0.9994612127543253`, 
      0.03282200785529918`}}, {{0.2022222222222222`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {0.9921701970481471`, \
-0.12489315469408459`}}, {{0.2022222222222222`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.9780096688347513`, \
-0.20855955424228392`}}, {{0.2022222222222222`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.9684918800506811`, \
-0.24904513300985678`}}, {{0.2022222222222222`, 
      0.36`}, {0.9635117236666388`, -0.26766613225610497`}}}, \
{{{0.26`, -0.04`}, {0.725154286202046`, -0.6885864224647483`}}, \
{{0.26`, 
      0.004444444444444438`}, {0.812118024886561`, \
-0.5834931993214238`}}, {{0.26`, 
      0.04888888888888888`}, {0.8811364875617238`, \
-0.4728620203477841`}}, {{0.26`, 
      0.0933333333333333`}, {0.9227870341189213`, \
-0.38531038094243536`}}, {{0.26`, 
      0.13777777777777775`}, {0.9387404583547154`, \
-0.3446249437402622`}}, {{0.26`, 
      0.1822222222222222`}, {0.9399044920889795`, \
-0.34143746975245315`}}, {{0.26`, 
      0.2266666666666666`}, {0.9359387379799902`, \
-0.3521628582750082`}}, {{0.26`, 
      0.2711111111111111`}, {0.9320161622080637`, \
-0.36241671233947326`}}, {{0.26`, 
      0.31555555555555553`}, {0.9298547993488174`, \
-0.36792669395950395`}}, {{0.26`, 
      0.36`}, {0.9295066796287508`, -0.36880527724740436`}}}};

ListVectorDensityPlot[data, MaxRecursion -> 4, VectorStyle -> Gray, 
 VectorColorFunction -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 \[Pi]), 0.8]], 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Comment: Your code runs fine on v12.2.0 Win7-x64. Try `Exclusions->None` to see if it makes a difference. Include the output of `$Version` to your post.

Comment: @Syed `Exclusions` not a valid option of `ListVectorDensityPlot`. Working with V13.0.1.

Comment: On 13.1 version, only when `MaxRecursion->0` work.

Comment: No black line in _v12.3.1_, win10. Please report this to WRI.

Comment: I confirm that the bug is absent in version 12.3.1 on Windows 10, but is present in version 13.1.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting `InterpolationOrder` to a even number circumvents the issue:

```
ListVectorDensityPlot[data, MaxRecursion -> 4, VectorStyle -> Gray, 
 VectorColorFunction -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π), 0.8]], 
 ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

I'm not sure why, though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the workaround!